# Put the menu link url in an attribute

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I need to make a menu without any links but with the url in an attribute.
The url should be in data-href="|" but now only the title will be printed in the attribute.
Is there a way to only return the url and not the link. ie. http://example.com instead of [Example](http://example.com)

Or does anyone know a different solution?

```
lib.mainMenu = HMENU
lib.mainMenu {
    entryLevel = 1
    wrap = <ul id="dropDownMenu">|</ul>

    1 = TMENU
    1 {
        noBlur = 1
        expAll = 1

        NO = 1
        NO {
            wrapItemAndSub = <li class="nochildren">|</li>
            stdWrap2.wrap = <span>|</span>
        }

        ACT < .NO
        ACT.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="active nochildren">|</li>

        # if has children
        IFSUB < .NO
        IFSUB.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="haschildren">|</li>
        IFSUB.allWrap = |

        # if has children and is active
        ACTIFSUB < .IFSUB
        ACTIFSUB.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="active haschildren">|</li>
        ACTIFSUB.allWrap = |
    }

    2 < .1    
    2 {
        wrap = <ul id="subMenu">|</ul>
        NO.ATagParams = rel="nofollow"
        NO.stdWrap2.insertData = 1
        NO.stdWrap2.wrap = <span data-href="|" class="link">{field:title}</span>
        NO.doNotLinkIt = 1

        IFSUB < .NO
        ACTIFSUB < .IFSUB
    }

    3 < .2
}
```

Comment: Should the link be removed only from the 2nd and 3rd menu level or from the 1st level as well?

Comment: @cascaval Only the second and third level

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (untested code):

```
lib.mainMenu = HMENU
lib.mainMenu {
    entryLevel = 1
    wrap = <ul id="dropDownMenu">|</ul>

    1 = TMENU
    1 {
        noBlur = 1
        expAll = 1

        NO = 1
        NO {
            wrapItemAndSub = <li class="nochildren">|</li>
            stdWrap2.wrap = <span>|</span>
        }

        ACT < .NO
        ACT.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="active nochildren">|</li>

        # if has children
        IFSUB < .NO
        IFSUB.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="haschildren">|</li>
        IFSUB.allWrap = |

        # if has children and is active
        ACTIFSUB < .IFSUB
        ACTIFSUB.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="active haschildren">|</li>
        ACTIFSUB.allWrap = |
    }

    2 < .1    
    2 {
        wrap = <ul id="subMenu">|</ul>
        NO {
            doNotShowLink = 1
            stdWrap2 {
                wrap >
                cObject = TEXT
                cObject {
                    typolink {
                        parameter.field = uid
                        returnLast = url
                    }
                    insertData = 1
                    wrap = <span data-href="|" class="link">{field:nav_title//field:title}</span>
                }
            }
        }

        IFSUB < .NO
        ACTIFSUB < .IFSUB
    }

    3 < .2
}
```

Comment: Nice it works. I just had to change nav_title//title to just title and add NO.doNotShowLink = 1. Thanks!

Comment: Well, I put `nav_title//title` because you probably do want the item use "Navigation title" if it's set for the given page.

Comment: I changed the answer per your comment.

Comment: Yes that's true but shouldn't it fallback to title if nav_title is empty? Mine is empty but no title was outputted.

Comment: Exactly! That's how it's supposed to work. Maybe I messed up syntax. Can you try `{field:nav_title//field:title}`?

Answer (score 1):

The above answer only works as long as you don't have any mountpoints. As soon as you have mountpoints in your page tree, these links will not be generated correctly.

To force a HMENU to output plain URLs without a surrounding a-Tag and page title even when using mountpoints, you need to define the IProcFunc property of HMENU.

I've written a small method which can be called through IProcFunc which will remove the a-Tags and replace the page title with the URL of the link.

```
<?php

class UserFuncUtils {

    /**
     * Modifies sitemap links. Whith this modification, a menu will only generate a plain url instead of an <a>-Tag
     *
     * This is an IProcFunc for a HMENU. The only parameter supplied by this method call is $this->I from the
     * Menu ContentObject. The function call expects a modified $I array to be returned.
     */
    function IProcFunc_plainURL($I) {
        // Show what $I has to offer
        // print \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\DebuggerUtility::var_dump($I, NULL, 8, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, array(), array());

        // Remove opening and closing tags and replace title with href attribute. This results in a plain URL being rendered by the menu
        $I['parts']['ATag_begin'] = '';
        $I['parts']['ATag_end'] = '';
        $I['parts']['title'] = $I['linkHREF']['HREF'];

        return $I;
    }
}

?>
```

Just save this small class somewhere (e.g. /fileadmin/libs/class.userFuncUtils.php) and include it with

```
includeLibs.userFuncUtils = fileadmin/libs/class.userFuncUtils.php
```

and then set the IProcFunc property of HMENU to point to this user function

```
lib.mainMenu = HMENU
lib.mainMenu.IProcFunc = UserFuncUtils->IProcFunc_plainURL
```

This should do the trick.